# Prove that given root of a polynomial is zero by approximation

Tags: polynomials

Let $\alpha$ be a root of a polynomial $a_nx^n + \ldots + a_1x$ with integral coefficients.

I would like to determine $\varepsilon > 0$ depending on $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ so that $|\alpha| < \varepsilon$ implies $\alpha = 0$.

Is it possible to give a "formula" for such an $\varepsilon$ without refering to the complete list of roots?

Comment: Root separation: 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Properties_of_polynomial_roots#Root_separation

Comment: @MattF. Thank you, that is what I am searching for. Do you know any good source (besides the one mentioned on Wikipedia)?

Comment: The accepted solution does not even use the fact that the coefficients are integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course we must assume some $a_j \ne 0$.  Say $a_j$ is
the one with least index.  Then you want $\varepsilon$ such that 
$p(x) = a_n x^{n-j} + \ldots + a_j \ne 0$ for $|x| < \varepsilon$.
You may use inequalities such as
$|p(x)| \ge |a_j| - \sum_{k=j+1}^{n} |a_k| |x|^{k-j} \ge |a_j| - m \sum_{k=j+1}^n |a_k|$

where $m = \max(|x|^{n-j}, |x|)$.  Thus $p(x) \ne 0$ if $m < |a_j|/\sum_{k=j+1}^n |a_k|$.

Comment: In your first sentence, the 1 in $a_1$ is a typo?

Answer (score 3):

Everything you wanted to know (and a little more) is in this paper by John Abbott

*Abbott, John*, [**Bounds on factors in $\Bbb Z[x]$**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jsc.2012.09.004), J. Symb. Comput. 50, 532-563 (2013). [ZBL1295.12010](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1295.12010).: